# NodeJS treatment of single quotes when in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, object, escaping

I'm finding that node v0.10 has a certain behavior that I can't replicate in Chrome. It automatically adds \ before every '

So this would be the script and outputs:

```
var test = "'test";
var testObj = {test:test};

console.log(test); // => 'test
console.log(testObj); // => {'test':'\'test'}
```

In the browser console, I don't see the \ automatically appended behind every '
Is this good and normal behavior for node? It's my current suspect for an issue I'm facing with using a certain NPM package, but I can't seem to force node to not escape the single quotes

Comment: I'm pretty sure it only appears that way for `console.log`, because it's trying to represent it as a valid object.

Comment: There is no difference! Your browser will just prettify the output before showing you it, Try paste this in chrome console: `"\""`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a difference in the implementation of `console.log()` from Chrome to node.js.  It does not make any difference to the execution of your code.

The node.js implementation of `console.log()` is trying to show `'test` as a valid Javascript string.  Since it, by default, quotes strings with a single quote when they are property values, the only way to show that is by escaping the embedded single quote.

This difference should have no effect on your running code in any way.  The underlying Javascript property is the same in both cases.  This is just an implementation difference in `console.log()` which is not governed by any open standard so each implementer makes some of their own choices on how to display the `console.log()` output.